# how to extract some data from a textfile in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm using visual basic.
I have a textfile like this:

> =hgh!
>   =3f4g!
>   item0=**orange**!
>   item1=**green**!
>   item1=**dog**!
>   item2=**apple**!
>   item3=**121**!
>   =312!
>   =1331!
>   =132!

I want to extract the texts which I showed in bold. They are not bold in the textfile, I just want to show what I want to extract and save in a textbox or textfile or listbox or whatever.

I wrote this code but doesn't work properly, I know that I should use a loop, but I don't know how.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i As Integer
    i = htmlText.IndexOf("=")
    TextBox1.Text = htmlText.Substring(i + 1, 4)

End Sub
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Explain a little more what you mean by "doesn't work properly". I'd expect textbox1.text to say "hgh!" based on your code. Does it not? Is this not what you want?

Comment: sample from microsoft. there are plenty of examples out there. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315828/?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: I can write the code like this:
    Dim i As Integer
       i = htmlText.IndexOf("item")
      TextBox1.Text = htmlText.Substring(i + 6, 6)
but I just get the "orange", but I want to put it in  loop to get all the bold words. and also because the length of each word is not the same, I don't know how to write it.